# Nunit | I want to set the value of priority to be dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, nunit, priority-queue, nunit-3.0

I am using Nunit and I've to set a priority for each test case, but I need the value of priority to be Dynamic based on specific condition after first Run

```
[Test, Property("Priority", "High")]
```

So is there any way to make the Priority "High" dynamic instead of set it static ?

Comment: why not make a separate test for each priority? is the assertion always the same for every priority? that would be strange..

Comment: did you already read this? https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/nunit-internals/specs/Dynamic-Test-Cases-Spec.html